# pthread_create return int value of -1; I am not sure what is this error code is

Tags: pthreads, posix

I am new to `pthread_create` and **posix threads**, I tried to develop a multi-thread program using `pthread_create`, but it fails with return value equal to `-1`. I tried to search what is this error code, but could not find any? Does anyone know what this return code (`-1`) means?

Answer (score 0):

According to [POSIX programming Manual](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_create.txt), the **return value** for the `pthread_create` functions is:

> If successful, the pthread_create() function shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

And the list of possible errors are non-negative.

But, for [`IBM z/OS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ptcrea.htm), for example, the **return value** can be `-1`:

> If successful, pthread_create() returns 0.
>
> If unsuccessful, pthread_create() returns -1 and sets errno to one of the following values:

So, I suggest:

- provide more context on what's the environment and standard library you use
- check the `errno` variable - it should contain the error code